# ssh command does not return same results as command executed under ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have one Linux OS server that I use to ssh to a bunch of other Linux OS Servers.
This is similar to a JUMP BOX.

Using the JUMP BOX, if I ssh to one of the servers, then execute:

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type f -perm -4000
```

I get a list of folders.

however, if I run:

```
ssh -q server.domain.com 'df --local -P | awk {"if (NR!=1) print $6"} | xargs -I "{}" find "{}" -xdev -type f -perm -4000'
```

I get folder errors.  The user that I utilize is on both boxes, and has password-less permissions.

I am trying to do this:

```
ssh -q server.domain.com 'df --local -P | awk {"if (NR!=1) print $6"} | xargs -I "{}" find "{}" -xdev -type f -perm -4000' >> output.txt
```

where the output of the command goes into output.txt.  In theory, I want the folders listed from the output sent to the remote server to append on a local file.

Where do I have this wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that you simple ' is not necessary when ssh-ing. Try without it $ ssh -q server.domain.com df --local -P | awk {"if (NR!=1) print $6"} | xargs -I "{}" find "{}" -xdev -type f -perm -4000 >> output.txt

Comment: That was it!!!!!  Thank you so much.  This was killing me.  Can you please put that in an answer format so I can give you points?

Comment: it's done, you can do it now if you want.

Comment: When you're trying to run a complicated command through ssh, you should consider writing a shell script that runs the command, install that on the remote server, and then use ssh to run the shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When issuing a command in a remote host with SSH it is not needed to use `'`, and it will lead to problems if you use it.

Anything that goes after the hostname you're connecting to, will be forwarded to the remote host, once connected.